# Gnome shell launcher is popping many pages dots after exiting app folder collections, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, suspend, gnome-shell, memory-leak

Gnome shell app folder bug:

[image: Gnome shell app folder bug]

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 for long time and since the beginning that above is occurring many times, my only hope was that it would be fixed with the final stable gnome version 3.36.3. But that didn't happened, the bug is very annoying and persistent (even with restarts) and recently the distro is very slow and uses insane amounts of RAM (Possible memory leaks after waking from sleep mode). The only option I have till now is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>r</kbd>, but not always solves the issue and I run that command everyday. Is there a way to fix this? Can I upgrade my gnome shell version to 3.38 or at least 3.36.7?

**Edit:** I restart the PC everyday many times, freezes and crashes are daily rituals. I always update software many times and personally check everyday.

Comment: Can you more precisely describe the steps that lead to this issue so we can try reproducing the issue?

Comment: To reproduce: Just go to any app folder on gnome shell app launcher menu, enter there and get out of it without choosing an app... And many page dots pops up and may cause memory leaks.

Comment: When you say, "get out of it," how do you get out of the Apps Overview? Do you pres ESC, do you click on the app-grid icon in the Dock, do you click on another icon in the Dock, do yo click on Activities, etc?

Comment: Well I mean "collapse" the grid by mouse clicking somewhere else outside of app folder area or frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a known bug. You can find some references in:

- [Bug #1870847: App grid has too many page dots on right](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1870847)
- [Bug #1889102: [ubuntu-dock] App grid has too many page dots on right](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1889102)

A first fix was released, as you can see in the first link, but the discussion about the bug continued in the second link and a real fix is not yet available. The second link contains also different videos that show how to reproduce the issue.

It seems that the bug is related to the Ubuntu dock extension and that [using version 69 of Dash to Dock extension may fix the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1889102/comments/7). Similar feedbacks are [available also in the first link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/1870847/comments/13).